# Convert kanji to kana on Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, japanese, transliteration

I want to convert kanjis to kana on Linux.

- Input: kanji, for instance 東京特許許可局
- Output: most probably kana, for instance トーキョートッキョキョカキョク
- Must run on Linux and be free, ideally open source.

Answer (score 1):

[Mecab](http://mecab.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mecab/doc/index.html) is pretty accurate for this.

It is open source.

## Installation

On Ubuntu 2015.10:

```
sudo apt-get install mecab libmecab-dev mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8
```

Yes you ned all of these packages, the `mecab` package alone won't do.

## Usage

```
echo 東京特許許可局 | mecab
東京    名詞,固有名詞,地域,一般,*,*,東京,トウキョウ,トーキョー
特許    名詞,サ変接続,*,*,*,*,特許,トッキョ,トッキョ
許可    名詞,サ変接続,*,*,*,*,許可,キョカ,キョカ
局      名詞,接尾,一般,*,*,*,局,キョク,キョク
EOS
```